# Format output to specific json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to format JSON to the specific values. My final goal is to convert
`-33.494 143.2104` to 
`{"lat":-33.494,"lon":143.2104}`

I am converting IP to geo location latitude and longitude:

```
python3.5 -c "
import geoip2.database; reader=geoip2.database.Reader('/geoip_databases/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'); 
response = reader.city('1.2.3.4');
print (response.location.latitude, response.location.longitude)"

-33.494 143.2104
```

Tried to convert it to the desired output:

```
python3.5 -c "
import geoip2.database; reader=geoip2.database.Reader('/geoip_databases/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'); 
response = reader.city('1.2.3.4')
;a=(response.location.latitude, response.location.longitude); 
b=('{"lat":' + a + '}');
c=b.replace(' ',',"lon"'); 
print (c)"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly
```

How can I accomplish following output {"lat":-33.494,"lon":143.2104} still having one liner?

Comment: How about you make your command line a real Python script, so everyone can read it more easily?

Comment: As much as I love a one liner, this is a bit much. You might want to look into pydash pick and rename if you are dealing with json files alot.

Comment: Instead of printing the two values, make a dictionary containing them: `{'lat': response.location.latitude, 'lon': response.location.longitude}`.

Comment: That will do the job, good point. Thanks. print ('lat': response.location.latitude, 'lon': response.location.longitude) Results with: {'lat': -33.494, 'lon': 143.2104}

Answer (score 0):

You can try with making a `dict` and doing a [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) soon after.

```
python3.5 -c "
import geoip2.database, json 
reader=geoip2.database.Reader('/geoip_databases/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'); 
response = reader.city('1.2.3.4');
loc_dict = { lat: response.location.latitude, lon: response.location.longitude }
print (json.dumps(loc_dict, indent=4))"
```